# Как защитить своё приложение?

Tags: android, google-play

Недавно издали новую игрушку в виде платной версии. Заимплементили проверку лицензии и т.д.
Но через пару дней люди уже умудрились ломануть/пропатчить так, чтобы хакнутая версия проходила проверку лицензии.

Поэтому, 2 вопроса:

1. Как этого избежать? Обфускация или
       ещё что-то?
2. Где бы почитать о способах взлома игр под Android,
       чтобы сделать защиту от них?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@KoVadim пишет правильно, что взлом дело техники. Здесь надо смотреть насколько усложняет защита саму прогу - в общем соблюсти верный баланс между количеством усилий на защиту и необходимостью защиты.

Из достаточно простых способов защиты упомяну:

1. Использование JNI вставок для проверки защиты, это просто, а вместе с тем на порядок поднимает уровень защиты - одно дело реверс инжниринг байткода, а совсем другое плюс к этом дизассемблирование JNI вставок
2. Пресловутый `if` проверки лицензии разбросать по коду в нескольких неочевидных местах - стараясь не использовать 1 функцию проверки лицензии, а использовать вставки кода вместо этого.
3. Внедрить механизм *in-app purchase - IAP* для покупки всяких уровней и проч. ерунды.
4. В IAP есть такая штука называемая *developer payload* - это такой механизм защиты правильности покупок. Если его правильно применить, то можно с помощью него проверять верна ли покупка. Более [подробно здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553515/why-is-it-important-to-set-the-developer-payload-with-in-app-billing)

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, 1) Чтобы это использовать, надо всё равно делать проверку в Java, а результат потом отправлять в C++. 
Вот если бы чекнуть лицензию можно бы было в С++ коде, тогда бы это имело смысл.

Comment: А мне часто с/c++ код в дизассемблере смотреть проще. Хотя на телефоне аrm... но может быть и x86.

Comment: @Suvitruf ну можно же чекнуть лицензию в С коде и там же  нарисовать UI диалог с предупреждением без выхода на Java и там же сделать аварийное завершение проги

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, просто я не встречал примеров работы с сервисом лицензий Google в native. Может поделитесь ссылкой?

Comment: @Suvitruf посмотрите [эту статью на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/179487/)

Comment: @KoVadim а я вообще никогда не смотрю ни в дизассемблере, ни в деоксе - ассемблер и байткоды меня вообще бесят :)

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, ооо, то, что надо. Благодарю.

Comment: @KoVadim так если С++ либу ещё обфускотором прогнать? Не думаю, что после дизасемблинга там будет что-то читабельное)

Comment: @Suvitruf насколько я знаю бесплатных обфускаторов для NDK нет, к тому же там сложность в том, что имя сишной функции должно быть строго определенным и соответствовать имени Java пакета/функции и проч., так что обфускация сишного кода будет с ограничениями.

Comment: > имя сишной функции должно быть строго определенным и соответствовать имени Java пакета/функции и проч.

Вовсе нет, ведь есть `RegisterNatives`.

Comment: @falstaf с этого места поподробнее...

Comment: @Barmaley, собственно, [вот][1].

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5833

Answer (score 6):

Какую бы мегазащиту Вы не делали, в конце-концов всеравно будет то место, где есть if, который проверят и пускает/непускает дальше.

Поэтому сделать идеальную защиту можно только одним способом - не выпускать приложение вообще. Тогда его точно не поломают. Но раз приложение поломали, значит оно хоть немножко, а популярно.

Что делать:

- обсфукация - это хорошо, тем более, что есть proguard
- убрать явную проверку лицензии. Например, можно проверить лицензию, а потом, аккуратно использовать этот результат для усложнения уровня.
- подгружать уровни с сервера.
- Посмотреть видео [Evading Pirates and Stopping Vampires](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnSNCXR9fbY).
- хранить уровни в [файлах расширения](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).
- сделать скрытую проверку на пиратов. То есть, используя сервисы статистики ([crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/), [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/)) и посмотреть, сколько по факту пиратов. Вполне может быть, что их пара процентов.
- Когда научитесь точно определять пиратов, можно просто переключать их на версию с рекламой. Но это нужно делать очень осторожно.